# ErrorException Undefined index: Secuencia

Tags: php, laravel

Me sale este error cuando intenco acceder al campo secuencia desde el modelo

aquí estaría el mensaje de error: https://flareapp.io/share/W7zlL8km#F61

```
    public function setAttribute($nextOrder){
        if(CRUD::actionIs('store')){
        $nextOrder = RouteElement::where('Busroutes_id', $this->attributes['Secuencia'])->orderByDesc('Secuencia')->first();
        echo $nextOrder;
        $this->attributes['Order'] = is_null($nextOrder) ? 1 :  ++$nextOrder->Order;            
    }
}
```

controlador

```
        CRUD::field('Secuencia')->type('number')->label('Orden')->wrapperAttributes([
        'class' => 'd-none form-group col-md-2 offset-md-1'
    ]);

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        CRUD::field('Busroutes_id')->type('number')->label('Id busroutes')->wrapperAttributes([
            'class' => ' d-none form-group col-md-2 offset-md-1'
        ])->default($_GET['id']); 
    }else{
        CRUD::field('Busroutes_id')->type('number')->label('Id busroutes')->wrapperAttributes([
            'class' => 'd-none form-group col-md-2 offset-md-1'
        ]);
    }
```

creo que todo esta bien y no se a que se debe el error

Comment: Agrega el mensaje de error completo por favor

Comment: Podrías subir el codigo de formulario tambien, y un poco mas de codigo del modelo.

Comment: @BetaM aqui tienes el mensaje de error https://flareapp.io/share/W7zlL8km#F61

Comment: En la pregunta por favor

Comment: @BetaM ya perdona